# What type of trim pot material to handle up to about 5mA wiper current

Tags: potentiometer

I'm working on a design that requires that I trim a couple of legs of a circuit.  It looks like 200 Ohm trim pots get me in the right area.  The wiper current on one trim pot will be somewhere between 1.5 to 3 mA, static (unchanging) after calibration.  The other trim pot will have a current that ranges from zero to a maximum of about 5 mA.

I know from past experience that having any DC bias across or through a plastic film pot or trim pot is a complete no-no.  The pot simply gets noisy and intermittent.

Although I have used Carbon pots and trim pots for decades, I find that they also get noisy over time.

I've had great luck using Cermet pots and trim pots.  However, my past usage of them is as potentiometers.  That is: the wiper current is a very low value, approaching zero.

In this case, I need to pass a few mA through the wiper.  I'm looking for guidance as to whether this is acceptable.

I did look at wire-wound trim pots (200R) but they are significantly expensive.  Too expensive for this product.

[Edit}

Both trim pots are for calibration and typically never change over the lifetime of the product (years).

What I meant by the one trim pot having a variable current is that the current changes as the signal level changes.  The pot itself does not move after calibration.

The other trim pot's current remains constant no matter what the signal level is.

Comment: \$ P = I^2R = {0.005}^2 \times 200 = 5 \ \text {mW} \$. I would expect that to be fine with any pot rated at 100 mW or more.

Comment: @Transistor I think it is less about the power handling capacity and more about the arcing with that level of current as the wiper is moved around and a concern that expresses a desire that whatever this product is, it lasts the consumer and serves well for a long time. It's not a use-and-throw-away product, my guess. I have to respect the experience (which he expresses) and the desire for long use.

Comment: Dwayne, My thoughts only: You know pretty much what is boxing you in, here. You have extensive experience, too. It appears that only one of the trim pots is a problem as the other isn't moved, once calibrated. (That could be replaced by fixed resistors, anyway, using a different calibration procedure.) It's the other one which I gather gets regular use. I imagine you either bite off the wire-wound (I trust your experience and I don't have a good suggestion) or show us the surrounding circuitry to see if we can imagine another entire topology to get the same job done.

Comment: I can say that cermet trimpots carrying a couple mA wiper current that are adjusted once and never touched again have proven to be extremely reliable (large quantities, operated 24/7), but that’s anecdotal experience.

Comment: According to me, almost all trim-pots are bad designed because the only force making a touch to resistive layer is a poor spring that becomes a weak over time. I can imagine something more reliable like fixing the wiper with screw nut what makes a more press (better contact). Regarding your question, i would use a higher resistance trim-pot with some amplification method (follower, OpAmp..)

Comment: @SpehroPefhany: Many thanks!  I am looking for other people's  experience and expertise.  What you said really helps.

Comment: Would a digital potentiometer be better instead, like the CAT5113 for $1.83 that has up/down controls? Since this is for calibration only, then blank PCB pads could be used in place of the pushbuttons to operate the up/down programming.